# What to do when gnome freezes up?

Tags: fedora

Fedora 13
    gnome 2.30.1
    kernel 2.6.34.6-54.fc13.i686

Sometimes my gnome just freezes up and I cannot click on anything.

What I normally do is press `ctrl + F2` and `pkill X`. To restart a new X server.

I am just wondering is they anything else I can do?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a consistent way/set of steps to reproduce this? If not, it might be a video card/driver issue. Are you able to use a different driver? If that doesn't  help, the card itself might be having problems.

Comment: It doesn't happen that often, and I am not sure how I can reproduce that, as I don't know when its going to happen. I am using HP Notebook Pavilion dv6000 GEFORE'GO 7400. However, I am just wondering if there was any other way to restart the windows manager, to what I have described above? Thanks.

Comment: I think that Ctrl-Alt-Backspace restarts X, though it's been a while so you might want to verify that somewhere else.